# jack2: error while loading shared libraries: libjackserver.so.0

Tags: sound, jack, audio-jack

I'm running 14.04 64-bit.

I downloaded the source `tarball` [file (1.9.10)](http://www.jackaudio.org/downloads/) for `jack2`, unzipped  it and then `cd`'d to the root directory.

```
sudo apt-get install libsamplerate0-dev
sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev
./waf configure 
./waf build 
sudo ./waf install
jackd
```

Command `jackd` results in the following error:

```
jackd: error while loading shared libraries: libjackserver.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I restarted my laptop without starting anything which might use any sounds. Still didn't work. I saw [this](https://github.com/jackaudio/jack2/issues/72) but don't really understand what to to.

Also done:

```
sudo updatedb
locate libjackserver.so.0
/opt/jack-1.9.10/build/common/libjackserver.so.0
/opt/jack-1.9.10/build/common/libjackserver.so.0.1.0
/usr/local/lib/libjackserver.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libjackserver.so.0.1.0
```

Comment: looks like you missing the library there. it might be on wrong directory or might not be linked properly during build. try to locate using 'sudo updatedb` and then `locate libjackserver.so.0`.

Comment: @AizuddinZali Updated with a link to a github issue!

Comment: I have posted an answer how to use ldconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to locate libjackserver.so.0. You can use `find` utility, but I rather use `locate`.

1. Update locate db:
   `sudo updatedb`
2. Locate the file:
   `sudo locate libjackserver.so.0`

This will return the file location if it exist. Taking example as `/foo/bar/lib/libjackserver.so.0`

In the link from your question, ldconfig is a dynamic linker.

To archive this(this steps working on 15.04):

1. Add/Edit `sudo vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/lib/libjack.conf`, add content:

```
#libjackserver shared object ldconfig
/foo/bar/lib
```

2. Run `sudo ldconfig`
3. Verify if the path is there, `sudo ldconfig -v | grep libjack`

Comment: Boom it works now, simple and to the point. Me like. May I ask, what happened here?

Comment: where is is your library path that you found the so file? It must be in the middle of no where out of ldconfig cache configured directory.  Therefore your program asking ldconfig where is the `libjackserver.so.0` library and ldconfig says, its not in my current cache. So we just need to tell ldconfig, hey here is the new library that was missing and viola! jackd is working!

Comment: I updated my question to include the file path! Alright!

Comment: aha so it was not in the default  library path. However there is another way where you can specify this during build time.

Comment: Can you please tell how to specify that during build time?